# Given list of API end points and it's priority, returns the API response with high priority

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I got this question in an interview. A weather API endpoint can return the weather data for Pincode, city, state, and country.

Given a list of APIs and their priorities, call them parallelly and return the data for the API, **which has high priority**.

```
APIs = [
  { url: "api.weather.com/pin/213131", priority: 0 },
  { url: "api.weather.com/state/california", priority: 2 },
  { url: "api.weather.com/city/sanfrancisco", priority: 1 },
  { url: "api.weather.com/country/usa", priority: 3 },
];
```

In the above list, the priority order is pin > city > state > country. This means calling all the APIs parallelly; if the API with Pincode returned the data first, resolve the Promise immediately; if not, it should resolve the next higher priority one.

I thought of Promise.race(), but that won't consider a priority. Then I thought of waiting till a timeout occurs, and below is my code for the same. It simply waits till timeout, and if the high priority one is resolved first, then the real Promise will be resolved. After a specific timeout, it simply resolves with the first high priority response. But the interviewer wants me to implement it without a timeout.

Below is the code with a timeout. Does anyone know how to implement it without a timeout and more generic fashion?

```
function resolvePromiseWithPriority(APIS, timeout) {
  let PROMISES = APIS.sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority).map((api) => {
    return () =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(api.url)
          .then((data) => resolve(data))
          .catch((err) => reject(err));
      });
  });

  let priorities = [...APIS.map((item) => item.priority)];
  let maxPriority = Math.min(...priorities);
  let minPriority = Math.max(...priorities);

  let results = [];
  let startTime = Date.now();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    PROMISES.forEach((promise, priority) => {
      promise()
        .then((data) => {
          results[priority] = data;
          let gap = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;

          if (gap > timeout) {
            // resolve the current high priority promise, if no promises resolved before the timeout, resolve the first one resolved.
            // If all promises are rejected, reject this promise.

            if (!results[minPriority] instanceof Error)
              resolve(resolve[minPriority]);

            for (let item of results) {
              if (!item instanceof Error) resolve(item);
              reject("No promises resolved !!");
            }
          } else {
            if (priority === maxPriority) {
              // if the high priority promise gets it's data, resolve immediately.
              resolve(results[priority]);
            }

            if (priority < minPriority) {
              minPriority = priority;
            }
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          results[priority] = err;
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: "*if the API with Pincode returned the data first, resolve the Promise immediately; if not, it should resolve the next higher priority one.*" - I don't understand. So if a lower-priority API gets the result first, it should take that one? Then how do the priorities get used at all? Is this actually about error handling - if the highest-prio API returned an error, only then consider the next?

Comment: This is tagged Node.js, promises aren't the right tool here IMO streams are - you can `.map` them just the same :)

Answer (score 0):

On the understanding that ...

> Given a list of APIs and their priorities, call them parallelly and return the data for the API, which has high priority.

expands to ...

> Given a list of APIs and their priorities, call them in parallel and return the data from the highest priority API that successfully delivers data; if no API is successful, then provide a custon Error.

then you neither want nor need a timeout, and the requirement can be met with three Array methods `.sort()`, `.map()` and `.reduce()` as follows:

```
function resolvePromiseWithPriority(APIS) {
    return APIS
        .sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority); // sort the APIS array into priority order.
        .map(api => fetch(api.url)) // initialte all fetches in parallel.
        .reduce((cumulativePromise, fetchPromise) => cumulativePromise.catch(() => fetchPromise); // build a .catch().catch().catch()... chain
    }, Promise.reject()) // Rejected promise as a starter for the catch chain.
    .catch(() => new Error('No successful fetches')); // Arrive here if none of the fetches is successful.
}
```

The `.sort()` and `.map()` methods are fully described by comments in the code.

The catch chain formed by the `.reduce()` method works as follows:

- the starter Promise is immediately caught and allows the Pincode fetch a chance of providing the required data.
- if fetch failure (Pincode or otherwise) gives the next highest priority fetch a chance of providing the required data, and so on, and so on, down the chain.
- as soon as a successful fetch is encountered, the chain adopts its success path; all further catches in the chain are bypassed; with no thens anywhere in the chain, the promise returned by `resolvePromiseWithPriority()` delivers the successful fetch's data; any lower priority successes are effectively ignored as they would only ever be considered in the (bypassed) catches;
- if all of the fetches fail, a terminal catch injects your custom 'No promises resolved' error.

Comment: This causes unhandled promise rejections when a lower-priority promise fails before the higher-priority promise settles, and even when a lower-priority promise fails after the higher-priority promise fulfills.

Comment: @Bergi True, This seems a practical problem faced in real-life apps. There could be some patterns, right?

Comment: I've not yet encountered a general pattern to solve these. I suppose it would be either "roll your own" (with `new Promise` constructor and `.then(…, …)` on each promise, although [generally discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569299/1048572)), or some sort of `Promise.allSettled`+`Promise.any`, or what Roamer did but with `.catch(()=>{})` to suppress unhandled rejections.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
function resolvePromiseWithPriority(apis) {
    const promises = apis
        .sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority)
        .map(api => fetch(api.url).then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res.status));
    const contenders = [];
    let prev = null;
    for (const promise of promises) {
        prev = Promise.allSettled([
            prev ?? Promise.reject(),
            promise
        ]).then(([{status: prevStatus}])  => {
            if (prevStatus == 'rejected') return promise;
            // else ignore the promise
        });
        contenders.push(prev);
    }
    return Promise.any(contenders);
}
```

The `contenders` wait for all `prev`ious promises (those with a higher priority) and resolve (to the same result as the current `promise`) only once all those rejected. Then they're passed into [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any), which will go with the result of the first contender to fulfill, or an `AggregateError` of all request failures in order of priority.

Notice a contender fulfills to `undefined` if any of the previous promises did `fulfill`, but this doesn't really matter - `Promise.any` would go with the first one. The code would work also with `Promise.allSettled([prev, promise]).then(() => promise)`, but imo checking `prevStatus` makes the intention a bit clearer.

The usage of `Promise.allSettled` (over `prev.then(() => promise, () => promise)`) and `Promise.any` ensures that the code causes no unhandled rejections.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have requests promises sorted by the `priority` field in `sortedPromises` array we just need to get the result of the first successful request:

```js
function getFirstSuccessfulResponse(sortedPromises) {
  let response = null;
  for (const promise of sortedPromises) {
    try {
      response = await promise;
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn('Could not get data from the request')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't call all the promises parallelly, it will call them sequentially. The solution should call all the API requests parallelly.

Comment: If we already have promises of requests that means they are already being executed in parallel. So all we need to do is to get the result of the first successful request and that's exact;y what's going on in the loop

Comment: So if the second request and all other requests already completed successfully and the first one will fail we will get the second result immediately.